# How can I allow everyone in my org to access an object uploaded by someone else?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

I maintain an S3 bucket for my org that is not publicly accessible but is readable by everyone in the org. There's also a folder, `sandbox`, that everyone in the org can write to. I setup my S3 permissions as:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "...",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "...",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::1234:root"]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "...",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::1234:root"]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/sandbox/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here, 1234 is a user in my org; I have enumerated all my users here. The first Statement allows read-only access while the second gives write to only the `sandbox` directory. These both work, but I've found that when people in my org write to it, no one has access to read those files except the individual who wrote it.

I instructed users to copy files there using `--acl bucket-owner-full-control`; for example:

```
aws s3 cp --acl bucket-owner-full-control my_file.tsv s3://my-bucket/sandbox/
```

But this doesn't fix the permissions. What's the right way to make it so I effectively own all uploaded files, or at least so that everyone can read files that anyone else uploads?

This is probably unrelated, but I also tried including a condition for bucket owner:

```json
"Condition": {
    "StringEquals": {
        "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
    }
}
```

I put this `Condition` as a sibling value to `Action`, `Resource`, etc., but when I try to save the permissions, I get the error:

> Conditions do not apply to combination of actions and resources in statement

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that you asked this on the assumption that users from different AWS accounts uploading objects.

Reading the description of the `bucket-owner-full-control` Canned ACL in the following [Controlling ownership of uploaded objects using S3 Object Ownership](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/about-object-ownership.html) page, you can get that it's applicable when objects are uploaded.
Thus, create another Statement with only `s3:PutObject` and you can give it permission with its condition.

The policy would be as following:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "...",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "...",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::1234:root"]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "...",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::1234:root"]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/sandbox/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "...",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": ["arn:aws:iam::1234:root"]
            },
            "Action": ["s3:PutObject"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/sandbox/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Take a look at this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html#API_PutObject_RequestSyntax) as well.
For instance, Request syntax of `GetObject` cannot be applied with `x-amz-acl`, but `putObject` is applicable.

BTW, this answer above is about the issue relevant to condition, not allows all the users from different account.

So, you can grant permission to another AWS account.
[How to provide cross-account access to objects that are in S3 buckets?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/?nc1=h_ls)
[Bucket owner granting cross-account bucket permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html)